# Updating existing Django app version

Tags: python, django

I was working through the tutorial for Django 2.0 when I had an earlier version of Django installed. I have now updated Django to 2.0.1 and Python to 3.6.4.

I am part way through building my app and I am getting an error when I try to include paths like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /films/5/
    path('<int:film_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /films/5/results/
    path('<int:film_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /films/5/vote/
    path('<int:film_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

The error I get is:

> ImportError: cannot import name path

Paths are not supported in pre Django 2.0, but this error still occurs after updating. Is there a setting within my app files that I need to change? I don't want to have to start from scratch if I can avoid it.

Comment: How did you update it?

Comment: I downloaded the python.pkg via their website. django updated via command line `pip3 install -U Django`.

Comment: are you using virtual environment?

Comment: No. i'm running direct from mac, no virtual machine.

Comment: How are you starting runserver? `python3 manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @Alasdair Oh my gosh. I cant believe I missed that. That is why. Please set this as the answer and ill accept it.

Comment: I missed the 3 previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed Django for Python 3 using pip3. Therefore you have to use `python3` when you run `manage.py`, for example:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Note that the recommended approach is to create a virtual environment (note the same as a virtual machine) for each project. See [this guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for further info. If you do this, you activate your virtual environment then use `python`.